# In an Angular 2 application, is it ok to change the index.html file to something else?

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 2 with the angular-cli. Is it ok to change the name of the index.html in an angular 2 app? I understand you'd also have to change it in the angular-cli.json file:

```
...
"index": "somethingelse.html",
...
```

Does the Angular and the angular-cli expect it to be called index.html (such as with routing or other hidden processes)?

Comment: yes its your option to change it. But the file must be in the root folder `src`